# Use in-memory SQLite database for WPF application database with EF6

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6, in-memory-database, system.data.sqlite

I am developing a WPF database-driven application using SQLite and EF6.  When the user opens a project (SQLite database), I would like it to copy this to an in-memory database, modify as the user edits the project, and when saving, copy back to file.

I have created the database and initialised the edmx with it (database first).
The target .NET framework is 4.6.1, restricted by a library I am using for communication.

I get that the SQLite backup API needs to be used, but I just can't quite connect the dots with how to get it all working with EF6.

This offered some hope, but seems to be based on EF Core, and I couldn't get it to work despite EF6+EF Core theoretically working together:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5086

This is where I've got to:

```
        //create in memory database
        var imdb = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        imdb.Open();

        //load stored database into memory
        using (var source = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=map_0_0_1.db"))
        {
            source.Open();
            source.BackupDatabase(imdb, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
        }

        //test EF
        using (var db = new dbContext() ) //????? how??
        {
```